# Is the phrase, "the vending machine was broke" acceptable?

Tags: tense

Is the phrase, "the vending machine was broke" acceptable, or do we have to say "the vending machine was **broken**"?

It seems perfectly legal to say, "the vending machine was restocked"; both restocked and broke are past tenses (of restock and break, respectively), so I would think "broke" is correct too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The word [Broke](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/broke) is also used as an adjective meaning *Without money*; however, that meaning doesn't fit into the context of your sentence. Therefore, a past-participle (broken) would be correct to be used.

> The vending machine was broken.

P.S. **restock** is a regular verb whose past and past-participle forms are the same (restocked). But **break** is an irregular verb whose past and past-participle forms are *broke* and *broken* respectively. Therefore, you can use *restocked* in your sentence which we would be being used as past-participle.

**Edit:** There are many verbs which in their base-form are used as an adjective, eg;

1. The airport is **close** at hand.
2. The bridge is **open** to traffic.

Comment: It is not immedately clear whether "broke" doesn't fit the context: If it's a machine that gives change it could have run out of coins; in that case one could jokingly say "it's broke". Unfortunately the OP does not give us any context beyond the machine.

Comment: As a native English speaker, I wouldn't consider *close* (being near) to be the adjectival form of *to close* (to shut). They're really two separate words which happen to share a spelling. (They may have some etymological connection, but that really doesn't make them related in the same way *open (adj.)* and *to open* are.)

Comment: @R.M. "They're really two separate words which happen to share a spelling." if there's any doubt: they are pronounced differently.

Comment: @PeterA.Schneider I'm not a native but I wouldn't even consider calling a machine broke just like I wouldn't use the term wealthy. To be broke you need to not be able to resupply at all and it's only a company that owns the machine that can go into such state. The machine is just temporarily out of coins.

Answer (score 3):

> *The vending machine was broken.*

No: in your examples "restocked" is a past participle verb form, not a past tense one. In a passive construction, replacing it with the verb "break" requires the past participle "broken", not the past tense form "broke".

Having said that, it is actually ambiguous here as to whether "broken" is a verb or an adjective, both of which have the same shape.

As a verbal passive it describes an event (*The vending machine was broken by the customer*), but as an adjectival one it describes a state -- the state resulting from someone breaking the vending machine.

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing these two sentences

> The vending machine was broken
>   The vending machine was restocked

The first one have got this structure:

[SUBJECT] [VERB] [ADJECTIVE] - [The vending machine] [was] [broken]

The second one have got this structure:
[SUBJECT] [VERB - PASSIVE VOICE] - [The vending machine] [was restocked]

You construct the **passive voice** with the verb **to be** followed by the **past participle** of the main verb, NOT with the past tense. Notice that there are irregular verbs, like **break**, whose past participle [broken] is different from its past tense [broke].

**broke** (in your intended meaning, if you want it to mean "damaged") is not an adjective nor the past participle so you can not use it in that sentence.

I think that

> The vending machine was broke [moneyless]

is not idiomatic. Vending machines has got no money of their own to spare.

You can say

> The vending machine has got no change, you have got to introduce the exact quantity.

if you want to reflect that the vending machine is not going to return the difference between the selected item's price and the inserted money.

Comment: *Broken* can be either an adjective or a verb in that sentence (see BillJ's answer). *Break* can be an adjective and it normally means "moneyless".

Comment: @userr2684291 I don't think that "The vending machine is broke" (neither broken nor break, the words that you mentioned) meaning that the poor vending machine have got no money is idiomatic. Bill J has stated that is difficult to distinguish between adjective and verb with such a small context.

Comment: Er, that was a mistake – I meant to write "broke" instead of "break". I didn't express my opinion on the actual sentence, but on what you wrote. The point is, *broken* **can** be interpreted as an adjective and a verb in that sentence, and *broke* **can** be an adjective in general (with the mentioned meaning).

Comment: @userr2684291 I've edited my answer trying to express that is not broke [moneyless] what I mean, it's the non-existent broke [damaged?]. And I was addressing the context provided, my answer is context-related, I think that it's not fair that you express your opinion [-1?] without taking into account that context.

Comment: *The machine was broken* – in this sentence, *broken* can be interpreted as an adjective or as a verb. In your answer you provide one analysis. I suggested reading BillJ's answer where it's argued that there are two possible analyses.

Answer (score 2):

Please note: In AmE English, there is increasing use of:

- The vending machine was broke. [instead of broken]
- The man was bit by the dog. [instead of bitten]
- The girl was took off the field by the coach. [instead of taken]

Now, **how do you want to sound?**

**The standard grammar here is broken, bitten and taken off** the field. This is the usage for passive sentences.

The standard form uses the past participle here. **For irregular verbs, that would be the "third form", as in bite, bit,bitten or take, took, taken for verbs with three forms.** Of course,**some only have two forms**: find, found, found. 
- He **was found** by the people looking for him.

If you do not use the standard form (by the way, people speak how they speak), your speech will be marked as (depending on whom is judging you): uneducated or regional or dialectal.

**If you were being interviewed for a fancy job, how you speak can make a big difference.** If you come from a region where people often speak like that (for example, Texas or Alabama), you would still be expected to *code switch and use standard English*.

"He was bit by the dog." is often considered the same type of speech as: "He don't do his work right". That would be using ***don't*** instead of ***doesn't*** in the third person singular of the present tense.

So, to answer the question: It all depends on how you want to sound.

Answer (score 0):

**to be broken** = to be damaged, to not (properly) work

**to be broke** = to have no money (broke = adjective)

BUT: we say about people to be broke, not about machines.

So in your context, "broke" is definitely not an option.

Comment: "broke" in this context is decidedly 'lazy' usage, but common in spoken English in some areas.

Comment: I am not sure what you want to say. Will you please elaborate a little more? Thank you.

Comment: Using "broke" in this way is basically slang. It is generally used in a knowingly un-educated manner. The speaker usually knows that it isn't 'correct' English, but does so regardless - to sound cool and trendy if you like. I wouldn't quite go so far as to call it regional dialect, but some people might.

Comment: Ah, now I understand. This kind of "abuse" is probably encountered in all languages. But, personally, I would avoid explaining how a language can be used "lazy" :)